# Windows 2012. Enable network adapter with only file system access

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, cloud

We ha ve a cloud hosted Windows 2012 Server. There is no plesk installed.

Accidentaly disabled the only network adapter, and now in revovery mode we only have access to the file system.

I need to activate the network adapter. Any ideas?

The only idea I have is to somehow execute a cmd command on the next startup that activated the network adapter with "netsh"

The problem is I don't know the name of the adapter, so I will need a command to enable all network cards.

Also, with only filesystem access, is it possible to execute a script on startup?

Answer (score 0):

In recovery console launch regedit and then load the hive from the server. After that you can edit the registry to launch scripts/commands on startup: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5d750877-9d17-4217-8b68-5eade1095493/enable-network-adapter-from-registry-or-file-system?forum=winserverManagement